# Http.request in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-connect, node.js-client

This is my code in node js:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = { 
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8124,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
};

http.request(options, function(res){    
    console.log("Hello!");  
}).end();

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){  
    console.log(err);
});
```

When I compile it, the compiler shows me the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOzIj.png)

edit: with the express works, but if I wanted to make it work without express how could I do?

Comment: Do you have port 8124 open? Check your firewall -- also run telnet to check: `telnet 127.0.0.1 8124`

Comment: isn't a port problem

Comment: Your getting an econnrefused which is either the ports not open or the service is not listening on the port. You should confirm that the port is open by running telnet

Comment: even if I put random port number and run many times wrong

Comment: instead if I create the connection with http. create server working properly

Comment: Putting random port number makes absolutely no sense. You MUST connect to a listening port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, it was enough to add to the previous code, the server code.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = { 
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8124,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
};

http.request(options, function(res){    
    console.log("Hello!");  
}).end();

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){  
    console.log(err);
});

http.createServer((req, res)=>{ 
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'})
    res.end()   
}).listen(8124)
```

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

```
const app = require('express')();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ ok: true });
});
app.listen(8124);

var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8124,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
};

http.request(options, function(res){
    console.log("Hello!");
}).end();

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

as you can see, it prints `Hello!` - when something is listening on port 8124. Your problem is on the server side, not on the client side. Specifically, the server that you are trying to connect to is not listening on port 8124 on localhost - at least not on this host.